# How can the F statistic of my anova test be greater than 1?

Tags: anova, variance, sums-of-squares, f-statistic

I've been digging into the formula for one way ANOVA test and I understand the we obtain the results from the ANOVA analysis with:

```
Group Sum of Squares/Total Sum of Squares
```

To see how much variance is explained. However, I also read that:

`Total Sum of Squares = Error Sum of Squares + Group Sum of Squares`

In that case, how could an F statistic be greater than 1? Shouldn't it always be a fraction of 1?

Answer (score 3):

The F is not GroupSS/TotalSS.

If it were you'd be right that it shouldn't exceed 1 ... but it isn't. You should re-read your sources (and preferably find several different sources).

In ordinary one-way ANOVA the overall F is the group *mean square* over the error *mean square*. Each mean square is the relevant sum of squares divided by the corresponding degrees of freedom.

If there's no group effects (they're all one population) then the F should be typically close to 1 (the numerator and denominator mean squares should both be unbiased estimates of $\sigma^2_\text{error}$). When there are group effects the expected group mean square includes a term related to the variation in group-means.

As a result (since there's usually at least *some* group effect), the F is typically greater than 1.

Comment: +1 A while back I went through the manual process of getting F [here](http://rinterested.github.io/statistics/anova_interpretation.html). It could possibly be of help provided R is not a barrier.